# Feeling sick after doing the crawl

Tags: swimming

I've been "swimming" once in a while for years, while on vacation for example, and never had a problem.  Recently I've been learning the crawl (freestyle).  I've finally got myself up to 20 meters or so without running out of breath.  But now, after swimming the crawl for a while, I feel sick.  I come out of the water and lie down, and things spin (as if I've drunk too much), and I feel a little like throwing up.

I'm pretty active.  I run and things like that.  Is the nausea a sign that I'm doing something wrong, or is it just part of getting acclimated to this stroke?

Comment: Is this one time occurrence, or reoccurring?

Comment: @JamesJenkins - It's happened over the last few days, as I've been doing the crawl longer distances.  No problems with the amateur-breaststroke I normally do for much longer distances.

Comment: Sounds like motion sickness to me. It's certainly possible to get motion sickness in a pool, I had a friend who could get motion sick while riding a bike on winding trails. I've never gotten motion sickness in a pool, but I have out on open water when the water surface is a little choppy

Answer (score 12):

This is most likely either a breathing problem, or a fatigue problem.  If your muscles aren't tired at all then it's probably breathing.  Given your description it sounds like you are hyperventilating.  If your muscles feel like jelly then it means that you're pushing too hard.  I've seen plenty of people puke (and have done so myself) after going harder than they were ready for.

Either of these is rather dangerous as breathing can make you pass out, and pushing too hard can make you cramp.  Both lead to drowning.

Comment: I think it's a breathing problem, too.  But I'm breathing like the internet said to.  Push out as fast as I can underwater to get all my breath out of my lungs, then every fourth stroke putting my head to the side (and slightly facing back) and drawing in.

Comment: @horsehair: NO!!  If the internet told you that, then well, shame on you internet.  Maintain a steady even rate of exhale while underwater.  Practice with just kneeling down in shallow water and leaning forward until your mouth goes under.  Better yet, find a swim instructor and take some lessons.

Comment: @cobaltduck - Thank you -- could you help me understand more?  From what I understand, I need to get all the CO2 out of my lungs, so I need to get all the air out of my lungs while my face is underwater (before I come up for another breath).  I'm actually failing at this a bit -- I have leftover air in my lungs when I come up (it's hard to push it out underwater fast enough).  Obviously swimming is exercise, so I need to breath oxygen at greater rates, and since the rate of breath is tied to the strokes (slower than running), I need to take more air in per inhale.  = more to expel while under.

Comment: @horsehair Are you counting strokes per hand or per same hand.  In other words, does 4 strokes mean two with the left and two with the right, or four with the left and four with the right?

Comment: @Kevin - breath, right arm goes under, left under, right under and up and breath to the left side.  I said four before but that seems to be a mistake (while I mime it outside.. and my wife just popped her head out of the door and asked if I was alright...)

Comment: @horsehair Your lungs are never full of 100% CO2. It's always a mix and when you exhale, you are exhaling a significant amount of oxygen. If you are holding your breath with your lungs mostly empty, then you are needlessly starving yourself of oxygen. The slow exhale is so that you are keeping oxygen in your lungs longer than the fast initial exhale while also not having to rush your exhale all right before you breathe. Also holding your breath is uncomfortable.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - so slow (normal speed?) exhale under water, emptying maybe half the lungs, then fill them up with a gasp when surfacing?

Comment: @horsehair I just wanted to explain that you're not merely expelling CO2 when you exhale. I'm not as much an expert on the best possible breathing technique for swimming, so I suggest you re-read cobaltduck's advice and if you can find a good instructor, that is the wisest and safest course.

Comment: SO is a QA site/ "Teach  a beginner swimming" does not fit the format well. best continue discussion  in chat.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't do more than 20 meters your stroke is really bad and/or your breathing technique is bad.  Bad swimming technique is incredibly exhausting, about the same a drowning.  As a beginner you will need to breath on every stroke in order to get enough air.  And as people have said here, you need to get all the CO2 out before the next breath, not easy to do at first.  Try swimming with fins until you get the hang of the stroke.  You won't struggle to stay afloat and the additional speed will make it easier to breathe.